# Auto-generating titles on Multiple plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting several plots in ggplot2 and saving them as one big PDF file with a different plot on each page. Each page is dedicated to one subject with 4 different variables per subject. I am creating the four variables per page using facet_wrap(). I am using the following code with the plyr and ggplot2 packages to create the PDF packet:

```
pdf("Subject.pdf")
dlply(dataFrame.Melt, .(Subject), function(x) x %+% x)
dev.off()
```

What I am looking to do is have a title at the top of each page that represents the subject's individual ID number. I can't seem to find a way to do this and I don't have a good sense of how to create some simulated data to adequately represent the size/magnitude of data I do have. If anyone has run into a similar issue, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: something like this, `pdf(); d_ply(df, "subject", function(d) p %+% d + ggtitle(unique(d$subject)), .print=TRUE); dev.off()`

Comment: Thanks, I got the code to work however it only prints the name of the first person in the data set on each page?